# Jamming Theory or DLVO Theory for Oobleck

Tags: home-experiment, mixtures

After doing some research I came across two theories that explain the shear thickening effect of Oobleck.  The DLVO theory which involves the suspension of molecules via two opposing forces [attractive (Hamker/Van de Waals) and repulsive (electrostratic)].  When a force is applied the attractive force (which reigns over smaller distances) temporarily overcomes the repulsive electrostatic forces.  This causes the particles to clump together and the mixture takes on properties of a solid. My question is which theory is the correct one in the case of oobleck.  The Jamming theory states that the sudden application of pressure, displaces the water that the starch molecules are suspended and move freely in.  This causes that particle to "jam" together (due to the low pressure zone created) effectively locking them in place.  This temporarily results in the oobleck becoming a solid.

**I know the description of the DLVO theory is quite watered down but I just wanted to speed up the answering process (if that's even possible) [More info on DLVO Theory](http://www.substech.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=stabilization_of_colloids)